# (UE4) Why does the ue4 basic mannequin not stay connected if i move the bones via blueprint

Tags: unreal-engine4

me and my Team are currently working on a bachelor project where we want to try full body capture using Optitrack so we can move a skeleton in Unreal. We have a full body suit with markers on it and several cameras to record our movement. We get the position and the orientation of the markers in our blueprint. Now we tried to move the bones of the ue4 mannequin and it looks like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_F63CGYKR3I&feature=youtu.be

As you guys can see, our skeleton does not stay connected (except for the arm) and we do not know why. We were wondering if any of you ever worked on motion capturing in unreal and can give us some tips how on to do it in a better way. Or how to fix our current issue with the Skelton (see prev vid). Currently we are using the [Transform (modify) Bone](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Animation/NodeReference/SkeletalControls/TransformBone/index.html) function to move bones and our Skeleton is the ue4 Basic mannequin.

Comment: Optitrack: http://www.optitrack.com/software/

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into skeletal retargeting. Your optitrack output is a skeleton that doesn't exactly match the unreal engine mannequin skeleton. I've used Ikinema for this purpose before, but Ikinema is a bit hard to work with - you need a licency, you don't get access to source code.
You might want to look into custom retargeting instead. Good luck!